# Seeing Wi-Fi password on Android 6.0/EMUI 4.0

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, password, side-loading

I couldn't find nothing on Google, nor Stack Exchange, sorry for duplicate.
So, I want to see a password to an connected Wi-Fi, without rooting my Huawei P8 Lite (ALE-21). 
 Is it possible to access /data/wifi/ using Ubuntu 16.04 or Windows 10, if I can't directly from the phone? A friend, told me something about giving full admin rights to a root explorer app (sideload)
 If nothing is possible, can someone explain me how to root Android 6.0/EMUI 4.0, accessing /data/wifi then delete the root and get back to the normal, like nothing happened? I don't want to damage my phone, I just want to access that section.

Comment: Are you using Huawei phone?

Comment: There is a very simple method which doesn't require root. Oops my bad for earlier comment, I understand you have a Huawei device so let me answer this straight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply back up your Wi-Fi settings using Huawei Backup application.

- Save the backup to SD card
- Navigate to this folder: `/sdcard/HuaweiBackup/backupFiles/xxxxxxx/wifiConfig.db` (where xxxxxxx is a folder with a date on which backup was performed.
- Using a file manager open the file **wifiConfig.db** **as text** (you need a **text reader** here try RB text editor -works even if not rooted)
- In that .db file there is a list of wireless SSIDs with thier corresponding passwords and choose the one you wish to know the password an you are done.

Comment: Let me know if you have any troubles, will be happy to assist further

Comment: Well i know about this trick, but I don't have any  "wi-fi settings back up" in Huawei's Backup App

Comment: Then you should make a back up and retrieve the settings, otherwise your other option will be to root your device

Comment: you mean restore the settigs? Why should I restore them

Comment: No, I meant just create a backup for Wi-Fi settings, then use that trick to get the Wi-Fi password. Isn't it what you were looking for?

Comment: The Wi-Fi option is available on the last option (where it is written **More** wait for it to fully load, you will see it)

Comment: all i have is this https://imgur.com/a/v1Qwr and when i back up manager, harassment filters it creates me "phoneManager.db" and "harassment.db" where i find nothing

Comment: I get your point, maybe the feature was removed in latest builds of the app, possibly due to this loophole, but if you really need the Wi-Fi password temporarily downgrade the app to version 7.0.2 or earlier there is an option for Wi-Fi & passwords (I have that feature). Cheers

Comment: Only version I find on google is 7.1.0 and 7.1.1 which is the version i have right now

Comment: could you give me a .apk with Backup please?

Comment: Sure I will send you the link, I downloaded the from Huawei official app store: http://a.vmall.com/app/C66323. But if you can't find older editions I will send a link to my cloud drive so you can download it from there if you're fine with that

Comment: i can't download it beacuse my ISP won't let me, send me the link to the older version (the version that lets me back up the Wi-Fi) please

Comment: uhhhh, you encrypted it, i need a pasword

Comment: I am glad it worked. Enjoy :)